# With pure HTML (no CSS) how do I have an image under text and an image to float right next to the text/image

Tags: html, html-email

My title kind of says it all really. I need to have text (left aligned) with an image underneath and an image to the right in html only (can't use CSS).

I'm a hesitant to share what I've done because you'll probably laugh but here is what I have (I'm not a developer, so bear with me).

[image: View here]

Comment: Add your code you can try something ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please give a little more information in order to have a better question (and answers): Why can't you use css? What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: What does "no css" mean? Does it mean "no external css files?" Can we use inline styles to the html tag? Can we use javascript to dynamically add styles?

Comment: If this is homework ("you can't use css"), you need to show what you know/tried so far.

Comment: @richb01 Can't use javascript and no external css files. I think I can use inline style.

Comment: I agree with others here...it would be helpful to see what you've done so far. I won't laugh, I promise. You'll find that people on SO are happy to help - even newbies. If your html is in email, then inline styles are OK.

Comment: I have just added an image that shows what I have (above in my main question). I'm not a developer so please don't laugh!

Comment: did you see my answer below ? is that what you are looking for ? if not, please comment on the answer with exactly what you want. thanks

Comment: @MihaiT I have thanks, I've just replied with another question. Any chance you could help with that?

Comment: yeah. i already answered it :)

Comment: You should paste the code into the question using the [edit] button, rather than link to an image of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have to guess what you want. but either way, the best way to do this is with `tables` . so here are some solutions

1. if you can write inline and if you want the image to the right, to be to the right of both text and image under it.

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="padding-left:10px;">TEXT HERE<br />
  TEXT HERE<br />
  TEXT HERE</td>
  <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:top"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

2. if you cant write inline and if you want the image to the right, to be to the right of the text only ( you can move it on the next row if you want it to be on the right of the other image )

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>TEXT HERE<br />
  TEXT HERE<br />
  TEXT HERE</td>
  <td><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

let me know if one of these is what you actually want

Comment: That's great, I've just tried and the first one worked. Just a quick question, is there a way I can indent the text a little by 10px or something?

Comment: yes . if you want `indent` which means only the first line of the text use this `<td style="text-indent:10px">` , if you want the whole text , use `<td style="padding-left:10px">`   . ( edited my first solution with `padding-left` ) if this is the right answer don't forget to rate it as accepted, thanks !

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working, this is what I've done:

<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
   <td style="padding-left:10px; font-family: Arial; font-size:14px; color:#5b585b;">
   Text here<br />
                 Text here<br />

</td>
   <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:top"><img src="images/radiators.png"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><img src="images/localStockist.png"><br />
 <img src="images/findOutmore.png"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>

Comment: well. it works. the `td` in which the `text` is situated, has a `padding-left:10px` so all it's content is moved from left to right by 10px.  isn't that what you want ? as you can see in this example , the text is moved from left with 10px : https://jsfiddle.net/6eL9ko3b/

Comment: Ah apologies, I wasn't indenting it enough to notice, sorry! That does work. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score -1):

Please use table format. each td add text and image in next td. that is pure html way.